# Create object from existing object Entity framework c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to copy full information of record to another in EF C#:

```
List<Cohort> AnYearsCohorts = oDB.Cohorts.Where(x=>x.Year == oCh.Year).ToList();
foreach (Cohort ochort in AnYearsCohorts)
{
    Cohort nChort = new Cohort();
    nChort = ochort;
    nChort.Year = Year;
    nChort.ID = 0;
    oDB.Cohorts.Add(nChort);
}
oDB.SaveChanges();
```

But got following error:

> {"The property 'ID' is part of the object's key information and cannot
>   be modified. "}

Comment: just remove this line: nChort.ID = 0;

Answer (score 3):

You probably have set ID as primary key and auto incremented so you can not change ID field explicitly in code.
Either remove ID as key or let ID increment automatically.